# Override display of content type using Views

Tags: views

How can I use the [Views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to override the output of a content type's display?

So that when a user visits a page/node created with this content type, it renders a view instead

Answer (score 2):

Use [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) instead, are designed for this very reason, [and more](https://www.drupal.org/node/946356).

Alternatively do this: Create a new node display (`admin/structure/types/manage/node_type/display`) with all fields you want and in Views, below "Format" there is a "Show" option, change it to "Rendered entity" and choose the node view you have created. The downside of this method is that all views advantages like: "Rewrite results", "Style settings" etc are not available, [ds](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) or [preprocess functions](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/7.x-3.x) should lift this weight if need it.